# ORDER BY word starts or inside field

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have an ajax-search on a mysql-db. Example: Search for "man" which I query with:

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE name LIKE '%man%;
```

I now want to sort the result to have all results starting with the search in alphabetical order:

```
man
mankind
```

after that I want to have all results width the search INSIDE in alphabetical order, like:

```
iron man
woman
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can order by the position of your search term in the string:

```
SELECT id 
FROM table 
WHERE name LIKE '%man%'
ORDER BY INSTR(name, 'man'), name
```

See also: [`INSTR()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_instr), [`LOCATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_locate)

You could also change the expression to only distinguish between start of the string or anywhere else:

```
ORDER BY IF(INSTR(name, 'man'), 1, 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can construct your `ORDER BY` using a `CASE` statement to verify the substrings.  Note: I am using `UPPER()` here to convert both the search value and the column value to uppercase, for a case-insensitive match.  If that is not your need, remove the `UPPER()`.

```
ORDER BY
  CASE 
    /* Matches the start of the string */
    WHEN UPPER(LEFT(name, 3)) = 'MAN' THEN 1
    /* Doesn't match the end or the start (in the middle) */
    WHEN UPPER(RIGHT(name, 3)) <> 'MAN' THEN 2
    /* Matches the end of the string */
    WHEN UPPER(RIGHT(name, 3)) = 'MAN' THEN 3
    ELSE 4
  END,
  /* Then order by the name column */
  name
```

*This method should be fairly portable, but I like the `INSTR()` answer below better.*

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE name LIKE 'man%';
UNION
SELECT id FROM table WHERE name LIKE '%man%';
```

Comment: I thought the same thing at first.. but when you order by... it's on the whole set returned by the union... so same problem -- this won't return duplicates... as UNION removes duplicates... UNION ALL would return duplicates